# Replace One Line of Multiline String In Python?

Tags: python, string

I have a multi-line string in python, and I want to replace a specific line number of it. I have a loop that goes through each line and increments the line number by 1, but what do I do when I reach the line I need to replace? Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show some code and data to illustrate your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
yourstring = yourstring.split("\n")
yourstring[lineyouwant] = edit
yourstring = "\n".join(yourstring)
```

lineyouwant is 0 indexed

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string = """line1
line2
line3
line4
line5"""
str_list = string.split('\n')
str_list[4] = "my new line value"
string = "\n".join(str_list)
print(string)
```